# How to output Zend log information to chrome debugger console?

Tags: zend-framework, google-chrome-devtools, zend-log

With Zend Framework 1.12 you can use `Zend_Log_Writer_Firebug` to write log information to the firebug console. Is there a way to pass the output to the chrome debugger console?

```
$logger = new Zend_Log();
$writer = 'production' == $this->getEnvironment() ? new Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(APPLICATION_PATH .'/../data/logs/app.log') : new Zend_Log_Writer_Firebug();

$logger->addWriter($writer);
if ('production' == $this->getEnvironment()) {
        $filter = new Zend_Log_Filter_Priority(Zend_Log::DEBUG);
        $logger->addFilter($filter);
}

$this->_logger = $logger;
Zend_Registry::set('log', $logger);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using [Chrome Logger](https://craig.is/writing/chrome-logger). It's a little bit more complicated than with Firebug but no big deal:

1. install the [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromephp/noaneddfkdjfnfdakjjmocngnfkfehhd) for your Chrome browser
2. include [ChromePHP](http://Zend%5CLog%5CWriter%5CChromePHP) in your composer.json (that's the way I do it - if you have a different application include path, put it there)
3. now you can use `Zend\Log\Writer\ChromePHP` to send debug-information to your Chrome-console.